# Re-rendering component despite same props

Tags: reactjs

I have an audio component that get it's source url from the parent.

```
export default class VideoPlayback extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <audio src={this.props.audioUrl} id="activeModuleAudio" style={{ width: '80%' }} autoPlay controls />
    );
  }
}
```

It's all working great and each time I pass the audio component a new URL the autoPlay starts playing the new audio.

The problem is that sometimes the URL that is passed is the same as the previous one, but I would still need to autoPlay the "new" source (the same as the previous one also). Since React doesn't see any change, it doesn't update the component and the autoPlay doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To force update component You can use built in method: `this.forceUpdate()` to re-render. Method also skips `shouldComponentUpdate` so component will be re-rendered always.

In Your situation I understand that parent component is container component so gets data and send it down to children, to avoid problems with sending props to children not mutate it but create new one using **immutable.js** or just create new object by `Object.assign`.

So if Your parent component has such code ( pseudo code ):

```
someData.audioUrl="newAudioUrl";
```

change it to:

```
someData=Object.assign({},someData,{audioUrl:"newAudioUrl"});
```

This solution is quarantee that prop reference will change even with the same url adress, so children component will re-render without forceUpdate.

Comment: I am into the similar kind of issue, I am setting state like this.setState({ navBarPinnedItem : e.currentTarget.dataset.name }); and passing navBarPinnedItem as props in child component.I want to re-render child component  even if props(i.e: navBarPinnedItem) are same can you please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to let React do its thing and just reset the current time when the component receives props. If the data doesn't change, why re-render?

```js
const audio = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/b/bb/Test_ogg_mp3_48kbps.wav/Test_ogg_mp3_48kbps.wav.ogg';

class Player extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.refs.audio.currentTime = 0;
  }

  render() {
    return <audio ref="audio" src={this.props.audio} autoPlay controls />;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { audio }
  }

  passSameProps() {
    this.setState({ audio });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.passSameProps.bind(this)}>Pass same props!</button>
        <Player audio={this.state.audio} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

↑ Audio autoplay warning!